# NServiceBus - Production Profile and endpoint not configured to be a publisher

Tags: nservicebus

I am new to NServiceBus, but have been able to get a Lite profile running locally.  I am now trying to determine the steps needed for deploying to Production and when I run the production profile I am getting an exception at startup.

I have two services, a command handling service which recieves .Send message, and an event handling service which recieves .Publish messages.  When starting up the Command Handling service, I get the following

> System.InvalidOperationException: Subscription message from eventqueue
>   arrived at this endpoint, yet this endpoint is not configured to be a
>   publisher.    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.<>c_*DisplayClass17.b*_16()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandledSubscriptionMessage(TransportMessage
>   msg, ISubscriptionStorage subscriptionStorage, IAuthorizeSubscriptions
>   subscriptionAuthorizer)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender,
>   TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage
>   msg)

The Endpoint configuration is clearly marked with AsA_Publisher.

Comment: I had the Configure.With().MsmqSubscriptionStorage in when everything was working smoothly.  In order to push to production I removed this, believing that the Profile would perform this action but it doesn't seem to be.  When I run Integration I do not get the subscription queue and get the same error as above.

Comment: If I add the .DbStorageSubscription then it works with db.

Comment: The Production profile will call Configure.With().DbSubscriptionStorage().  It expects that the configuration for it is in you app.config, do you have that defined?